# Can only access computer IP 192.168.1.3 sometimes (localhost always works)

Tags: apache, localhost, ip-address, wampserver

I have a problem, and maybe I don’t know what do search for, but I haven’t been able to find any threads with a similar problem. So I hope that any of you can point me in the right direction or suggest a solution.

I have a wampserver running on localhost, and I have created a database and a webpage that is using this. When I enter localhost/myproject in the browser the project is displayed. I need to access this site from another device on the same network though, and for that reason I need to use the IP Address of the computer hosting the server (this is 192.168.1.3).

The problem is, that the computer IP is only accessible sometimes. Meaning – if I enter 192.168.1.3/myproject in the browser window, sometimes it will display the webpage as it should while other times it won’t. It either gives me a message of something like “runtime out” or it just keeps trying but never does anything. I can always get access to the router using the IP 192.168.1.1, and here I see the computer 192.168.1.3 even when I can't connect to it.

A while ago I changed the Apache file httpd.conf and added “Allow from 192.168.1.3” under Directory. I did this because I got a message of “access denied” when entering the IP in the browser, and I found a thread posting this solution – which worked. I also created an exception for port 80 in the windows firewall in this process.

I don’t know what to do now though. Any help/suggestions would be very much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase timeout intervals in your php.ini file

If sometimes it's works, and sometimes - no, problem in timeout

Comment: Thanks. I tried changing session.gc_maxlifetime. And I forgot that I also previously increased max_execution_time. So far it is working, but that might just be a coinsidence. Truth is, I really don't have any idea which elements should be changed. Can you possible suggest specific elements? I will give the current setup some time and accept your answer tomorrow if it seems to have done the trick :)

Comment: Unfortunately this solution stopped working. I have tried changing other elements in the php.ini file and I have searched for information about timeout intervals - but with no luck.. Could you possibly explain why it should be a problem in timeout? That might help me understand what to search for..